# Why it's not slow when watching movies on storage

Tags: cpu-architecture

I am not sure if I can post a question without code in Stack Overflow. This is a question about how the computer works.

I know it's not slow when watching a movie because the data in storage is copied to memory and used. However, because the storage processing speed is slow, is it not slower than a direct processor accessing and reading the storage? Or does another device act as a copy? I want to know the principle in detail.

Comment: I don't really follow. It's fast enough because it's fast enough. If it were not fast enough, it would not be fast enough. Adding a fast device cannot make another, slow device faster. What do you want to know exactly?

Comment: "I can drive in my car to the next city in one hour*. I'm surprised my car is fast enough to do that. How does it work? Does another vehicle act as a copy?" _(* Please don't do this during lockdown!)_ No, it's just fast enough, end of story!

Comment: Possibly related: [What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory?](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf) - DRAM is much faster than a hard drive or optical disk so it's fine to DMA into RAM before the CPU reads it.  You don't want to waste CPU time reading small chunks at the speed the disk can produce them (PIO: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmed_input%E2%80%93output)

Answer (score 1):

The processor access *addressable* data: units of memory each one identified by an address.

Main memory is addressable: this allows the processor to read from "here" and write "there" and "there", exploiting the full capacity of the main memory.
Without memory, the processor could only use its internal units of storage (registers) but they are of limited size (around 2KiB for x86, but for general purpose registers it goes down to 128 *bytes*).
Caches are equivalent to memory for this discussion.

Disks are not addressable the same way memory is: this is due to historical reasons (small address space) and performance (reading randomly is worse than planning ahead even for SSD, also there are more commands than Read and Write and some can be executed in parallel).
So disks are either made to write data to main memory (DMA) or there is a fixed location where to write to send commands and a fixed location to *repeatedly* read from to fetch all the data (PIO).
This read location is small enough to fit into a CPU internal storage unit but once the CPU has the data it must "save" it somewhere for later processing and so this data would end up in memory anyway (PIO is waaaay slower than DMA).

Note that Non Volative Devices are considered a new form of storage, something in between main memory and disks (while main memory won't be phased out by NV devices, because we need scratch memory, disks may be if the NV technology can address the longevity and density problems without affecting performance).
They are addressable like main memory and thus the CPU could read directly from them.
Symbian OS based mobile phones worked this way: the OS executable files were stored in the flash ROM (which is an NV device) and read directly by the CPU without loading them (they were already loaded).

Also note that FWIW, video is played for humans which have a very slow sampling rate. We only need about 24 frames per second to consider a movie smooth, that is easy to sustain even from the network (though it depends on the resolution and format).
So the disk has all the time to serve the reads needed for the playback.
On the contrary, video conversion can be affected by the speed of the disk.

Also, videos are compressed so the CPU must modify the data (meaning it needs to overwrite it or store the result somewhere in main memory) to play the video unless there is a hardware device that can play compressed stream directly and the file format is just right.
In this case, storing the video on an NV device would allow a faster reproduction, without the CPU involved or any copy in memory. 
However the speedup is not dramatic, we are shaving off the time needed to read from memory not the time needed to read from the storage device (which is still the dominant factor affecting speed). 
That's mostly irrelevant for the frame rates involved when playing for humans.